# Groovlet not working in GWT project, container : embedded Jetty in google plugin

Tags: gwt, groovy, jetty, groovlet

I am working on a GWT application which uses GWT-RPC.
I just made a test groovlet to see if it worked, but ran into some problems

here's my groovlet

```
package groovy.servlet;
print "testing the groovlet";
```

Every tutorial said we don't need to subclass anything, and just a simple script would act as a servlet.

my web.xml looks like this -

```
<!--  groovy -->
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>testGroovy</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.testGroovy</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testGroovy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping
```

When I Run as -> web application,
i get the following error from jetty :

```
 [WARN] failed testGroovy
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class groovy.servlet.testGroovy is not a javax.servlet.Servlet
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.checkServletType(ServletHolder.java:377)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:234)
 at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:616)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:447)
 at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:115)
 at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
 at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:543)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:421)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1035)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:783)
 at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:275)
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use  groovy.servlet as the package for you class? Also are the groovy jars deployed as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building a new class there, not extending the HttpServlet class (or the groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet either).

GroovyServlet *is* the servlet, that then interprets your groovy script.

To set it up in web.xml you use

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>GroovyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>groovy.servlet.GroovyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>GroovyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.groovy</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then in a file named something.groovy somwhere under your web root you can write

```
out.println 'testing the groovlet'
```

The objects `request`, `response`, `session`, `params` and others are also present at your disposal. So that you for instance can write

```
out.println "Hello ${params['name']}"
```

More info at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovlet